# CCParticleSystemQuad crashing with error "Abnormal error in particle quad"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

The code just crashes when an already running particle effect's setVisible property is changed to NO, and later turned to YES. I have been working with ParticleEffects for a while now but never have I faced this error before. I don't know where I am going wrong. Its so frustrating. Please any help would do wonders. Im using cocos2d 2.x, xCode5 and well ofcourse Ive generated my ParticleEffects through ParticleDesigner. Hoping someone will help me out here.Thanks though :)

Comment: it would help if you could add an exception breakpoint and post fault producing code..

Comment: Here you go, this is exactly what it states:
*** Assertion failure in -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw], /Users/MacbookPro/Documents/orb/Orb/libs/cocos2d/CCParticleSystemQuad.m:448

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also and found that it was a cocos2d bug. The fix was added here https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/6032/files and you can copy the changes if you don't want to update. (Seems to have worked well for me anyways.)